# How to declare argv[1] in header file

Tags: c++, root-framework

The c++ code that I wrote has two file one is main file (*.C ) and another file is (*.h). I need to use argv[1] in the header file (*.h). How can I do this?

Actually this file is written to run through root.

some contents of my AnalyzeTree.C file is

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    AnalyzeTree t;
    t.Loop();
    return 0;
}
void AnalyzeTree::Loop()
{
   TFile *hfile = new TFile(argv[2],"RECREATE");
.
.
.
}
```

Some content of AnalyzeTree.h file is

```
AnalyzeTree::AnalyzeTree(TTree *tree) : fChain(0) 
{
   if (tree == 0) {
      TFile *f = (TFile*)gROOT->GetListOfFiles()->FindObject(argv[1]);
      if (!f || !f->IsOpen()) {
         f = new TFile(argv[1]);
      }
      TDirectory * dir = (TDirectory*)f->Get(TString(argv[1])+":/demo");
      dir->GetObject("tree",tree);
   }
   Init(tree);
}
```

Presently the error that I am getting is

```
In file included from AnalyzeTree.C:2:0:
AnalyzeTree.h:29:35: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’
AnalyzeTree.h: In constructor ‘AnalyzeTree::AnalyzeTree(TTree*)’:
AnalyzeTree.h:201:62: error: ‘argv’ was not declared in this scope
AnalyzeTree.C: In member function ‘virtual void AnalyzeTree::Loop()’:
AnalyzeTree.C:42:29: error: ‘argv’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Pass `argv[1]` to a function in the header.

Comment: argv is an argument to main, declare main as something like `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: Why do you want to use it in the header file? Please explain

Comment: @abelenky Now I added some part of my code.

Comment: @Quest Actually I am using root (data analysis framework based on C & c++). So, There is a command MakeClass by which based on my data in root file it automatically creates .C & .h file. Where the name of data file is in .h. And I need to run this program for different data.

Comment: You can declare your function in the .h file and define it in the .c file.

Comment: You don't use `argv` directly in the class. That's not how classes are meant to be designed. You simply pass `argv` as a parameter to your constructor.

Comment: This should be reopened. With the added code it's perfectly clear what's being asked.

Comment: @CareyGregory now it's clear. But check this post before edit.

Comment: @Quest Yeah, I just did and edited my comment to reflect that.

Comment: Nothing in the code shown would produce `error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’`. Is that message from an earlier version of the code? The code and error messages in the question need to be in sync.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't matter but, shouldn't the file be named `AnalyzeTree.cpp`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: `.C` (capital C) is an accepted way of signaling that the file is C++. `.cpp` is not the only alternative. Other extensions recognized by `gcc` are `.cc`, `.cp`, `.cxx`, `.CPP`, and `.c++`. (I normally use `.cc`)

Comment: Now I got it. I need to pass the arguments to the Loop() function and then it will work.

Actually it was my old question that I am trying to fix because of get rid of restriction of posting from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

First: Read a C++ (possibly beginner) book. Click on the [C++] tag here to find good books.

Second: You can pass argv[1] via a parameter. Have AnalyzeTree constructor take an additional std::string const& argument.